# Should I capitalize the first letter of prototype objects the same way that constructor functions are capitalized?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

It is standard practice to capitalize the first letter of constructor functions.

For example,

`function Creator() {}`

`function Origin() {}`

Is it also standard practice to capitalize the first letter of prototype objects?

For example,

`var Creator = { }` vs `var creator = { }`

I know it will work either way and I'm not trying to start a debate but is their an industry standard for prototype objects? I hate to write code in a way that is a dead giveaway that I'm a noob.  Thanks!

Comment: Its purely stylistic choice, but in general no. Also, `const creator = {};` is just an object literal, not a 'prototype' object.

Comment: Usually, if something is "`new`able" (has a prototype), it's named in CapitalCamelCase. Specific example: if you use ESLint, there's a rule that forbids creating an instance if the name isn't capitalized: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an industry convention for naming prototype objects?

Not that I know of - mostly because prototype objects are not very common. The industry standard is to use `class` syntax or `ConstructorFunction.prototype` in ES5.

Objects with capitalised names typically denote namespaces (e.g. modules, singleton objects, "classes" with static functions), or - rarely - factory functions (for people who avoid `new`). Using the same naming convention for prototype objects might lead to confusion.

You still can do it if you are comfortable with it, just make sure to document your standard and be consistent about following it. Personally I would recommend to use prefixes and suffixes, like `…Proto` for prototypes and `create…` for factories.